# Jenkins to Stash Notifier Plugin error despite correct credentials

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server

I have set up a post build action on Jenkins to notify Stash about the result of the builds. However, I get an error which says:

```
Failed to notify Stash for commit <sha1> ({"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"CAPTCHA required. Your Stash account has been marked as requiring a CAPTCHA to be solved before you may login again. This is typically caused by too many attempts to login with an incorrect password.\nIf you are currently logged in to Stash via a browser you may need to logout and then log back in in order to clear the CAPTCHA.\n\nVisit Stash at <link> for more details.","exceptionName":null}]})
```

However, I have set the correct credentials for the Stash repo (under Access Keys) and the private key is on Jenkins. Moreover, when I push a commit into Stash, Jenkins triggers and starts building. So I conclude it's not a credentials issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message indicates your Stash account need to be unlocked (with the CAPTCHA). Maybe you did some attempts with a wrong password (with Jenkins).

Log into Stash with the relevant account (find out which in the global Jenkins settings), enter the correct CAPTCHA.

It will unlock your account and Jenkins will be able to notify Stash.

Comment: I do not understand. Whats this got to do with me logging into Stash? I just want the build details seen under the respective commit in Stash. I have already set up the SSH credentials on Jenkins and Stash which should enable communication between the two of them. I have left the Notify Stash under Jenkins post build actions empty. Should this not be enough?

Comment: Your SSH key is associated to a Stash user. This user seems to be locked. Can you try to login into Stash using this user?  Stash will certainly prompts a CAPTCHA to unlock your account.

Comment: Oh yes now i get it. I forgot that I had set up a separate Jenkins user in the global settings in Jenkins to access Stash. I will log into Stash using those credentials and try again. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yep exactly, the Jenkins plugin is using some credentials in the global Jenkins settings :)

Comment: Yup, I have completed the entire set up now and it works like a charm. Great learning experience this. Thanks a lot for your help @Bruno Lavit.